# Evince and fit-to-page mode

Tags: evince

After clicking a link in a PDF file, Evince goes back to the "fit-to-page" mode instead of my favorite one, the "full-page-width" mode. It is a bit annoying. How can I change that ? I don't see anything in the preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jpdfbookmarks-2.5.2, this tool can change the default boorkmark's 'fit-to-page' to 'full-page-width'. I have used this tools to change many pdf files's default behavior. It's a little time-consuming. I have no time to change every pdf I read. So I give up and find easy trade-off way.

Evince has a shortcut key 'w'.
Just tap 'w', evince will show in 'full-page-width' mode.

Comment: Great I did not know the shortcut key 'w' for evince. I am going to try jpdfbookmarks.

Comment: This software is not maintained, but it still work on Ubuntu 22.10. I don't understand the explanation above. I selected all the bookmarks, set the width to original size and set the destination. The application ask if you want to keep the same destination for all the bookmarks. You say yes. That's it. I guess "original size" is the same as keep whatever selection is set on Evince.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Save Current Settings as Default" menu action to save the current settings and apply them to new documents that don't have metadata.